# Highcharts - Keep tooltip showing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I have a highcharts graph, and I allowed the user to dynamically create their own Flags. Now I want to be able to click on the flag itself and be able to keep it's tooltip showing the whole time until I click on the flag again. The reason for this is to allow the user to give special meaning to points, and when they save the graph as an image, I want it to show the tooltip information they left on.

Anyone know how to do this or go about this? I can't figure out how to access the flags tooltip

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                animation: false,
                dataGrouping: {
                    force: true,
                    smoothed: true
                }
            },
            line: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                animation: false,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            var thePoint = this;
                            var previousFlag = findFlag(thePoint);
                            if (previousFlag != null) {
                                previousFlag.remove();
                            } else {
                                createFlagForm(thePoint);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            flags: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() { 
                            //How to access the tooltip? this means the flag point itself
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    xDateFormat: "%B-%e-%Y %H:%M"
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I just whipped this up.  When you click a point it will persist the tooltip.  It does this by cloning the tooltip svg element and appending it to the plot.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/SeCAB/1/).

```
$(function () {
    cloneToolTip = null;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() { 
                            if (cloneToolTip)
                            {
                                chart.container.firstChild.removeChild(cloneToolTip);
                            }
                            cloneToolTip = this.series.chart.tooltip.label.element.cloneNode(true);
                            chart.container.firstChild.appendChild(cloneToolTip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});​
```

Comment: Wow! I am amazed how you did that. So were you just fiddling with their library or did you look through their source code or something? Sorry I can't click on your post being useful. I don't have enough reputation. +1 if I could

Comment: Excellent demo! However it does not work if we have set `tooltip: {useHTML: true}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @whuhacker, here's an updated fiddle for `useHTML: true`:  http://jsfiddle.net/SeCAB/45/, you have to apply the above functionality to both the SVG portion of the tooltip and the HTML portion.

Comment: I want to do this, but I want it to show ONLY when a user clicks and not when hovering. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: When i back to this chart from link (trough browser "back" button), clicks do not work.
Only page reload help.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's solution is excelent, here is a similar much basic solution:

```
tooltip: {
            stickOnContact: true,
        },
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.stickOnContact

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).