# Highcharts: tooltip Click instead of hover

Tags: highcharts

Is there a setting for highcharts tooltips where you can set it to display on click versus hover?

I have seen a lot of people discussing the tooltip staying on click but then there is still the hover present. Is there a way to disable the hover and use only click?

Comment: Did you see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476400/highcharts-keep-tooltip-showing-on-click

Comment: Yeah that works fine and yes I did see that one. The only problem was that I was trying to get rid of the hover all together and making it only a click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a setting for that in Highcharts currently.

There is a feature request for this functionality here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2607304-allow-the-tooltip-to-appear-when-a-point-is-clicke

Feel free to add your votes and comments.

UPDATE:

I have started using the jquery UI dialog for this purpose.
I disable the tooltip in Highcharts, and add a click event to the point in the plotOptions.

In that click function I call an external function, sending it the point object, and build my tooltip within the dialog.

- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click

You could also use Highslide for this purpose, and keep it all in the family.

- http://highslide.com/

Working `example:`

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LHZ3E/embedded/result/

Comment: The working example is excellent and demonstrates a ton of functionality with HighCharts. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Adding for those who has problems like me with `useHTML: true` and wants to display tooltip **only** on click and not on hover and wants to have only one tooltip on screen.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aespichan/0je10ur7/3/).