# Edit Yaxis values using textbox in popup

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to edit Highchart Yaxis values on double clicking series point using popup with textbox same like attached snapshot URL, on pressing ok or enter button chart must be redraw with changed values.

Any help would be appreciated.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE658CD68AB0C97A!2696&authkey=!ALdbY9xxPI2oxYY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example for using a popup on click:

- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

See the answer here for another way, using jQuery dialog:

- [Highcharts: tooltip Click instead of hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946044/highcharts-tooltip-click-instead-of-hover/16947143#16947143)

You can capture the result of the update, and send it to the `point.update()` method, reference here:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update

If you have more specific questions, get an example going and ask away.