# How to make a rendered label in Highcharts always visible and still relative to the point clicked or hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

As well as a tool tip that opens on a click I also need a different tool tip that opens on mouse over.

I have tried to use the render.lable however when the label is render it can sometimes go off the chart area and become unreadable. 
Is there a way to make the rendered label not go out the chart area or position over the top of the chart?

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts custom label'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function (chart) { // on complete
    var point = chart.series[0].points[8];
    chart.renderer.label('Max observation', 340, 50, 'callout', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop)
        .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        })
        .attr({
            position: 'absolute',
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            r: 5,
            zIndex: 999
        })
        .add();

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/54tnht7b/

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this differently.

I would use the standard functionality of the tool tip for the part that you need activate on hover, and use a separate pop up on click.

See this answer for an example:

- [Highcharts: tooltip Click instead of hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946044/highcharts-tooltip-click-instead-of-hover/16947143#16947143)

Comment: Yes your right... I had some extra setting in the tooltip section that was stopping the standard tool tips from opening. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.renderer.label('Max observation', 340, 50, 'callout', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop)
    .css({
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    })
```

In this block you set the location of the label to a region which isn't on your chart.

```
 chart.renderer.label('Max observation', 250, 50, 'callout', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop)
    .css({
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    })
```

Here it is changed to be back on the chart. Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/54tnht7b/2/

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: No.  The 250 and the 50 would actually come from the mouse over point event plotX and plotY. 
jlbriggs actually pointed out that I was just going about this the wrong way and so I have now corrected my evil and every thing works ok :)