# Show multiple Tooltips in highcharts on overlapping points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Need to show multiple tooltips in the highchart only when multiple series points are overlapping.

same functionality I can achieve through the below link.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918567/showing-multiple-tooltips-in-highcharts-simultaneously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Pfe.png)

But the only problem I am facing here is always showing duplicate tooltip on hover over the single series (Unlike the above example here I am using time-series chart so that the line points will be continuous).

please help me to solve this problem.

---

[image]

Hi @ppotaczek, 
This is the issue I am facing in this fiddle - **brfLdv7o**

Showing a blue tooltip, Even though I hovered the yellow series line.
please check the attached screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tooltip.split` property to render multiple tooltips and hide unnecessary ones in tooltip `refresh` method wrap:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(proceed, points) {
        var split = false,
            labels;

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        labels = this.label.element.children;

        for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
            if (
                points[i - 1].x === points[i].x &&
                points[i - 1].y === points[i].y
            ) {
                split = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!split) {
            points.forEach(function(p) {
                if (p.hoveredPoint) {
                    labels[p.series.index].setAttribute('opacity', 1);
                    p.hoveredPoint = false;
                } else {
                    labels[p.series.index].setAttribute('opacity', 0);
                    p.setState('');
                }
            }, this)
        } else {
            points.forEach(function(p) {
                labels[p.series.index].setAttribute('opacity', 1);
            })
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function(event) {
                        this.hoveredPoint = true;
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },

    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ymr1xbnh/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.split

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.mouseOver

Comment: Iam using highcharts-angular v2.3.1. Tried your code not working properly. Sorry that  I can’t share the code base as Iam working on banking domain.

Comment: Found out the root cause. Your approach won’t work for the larger data, that is Timeseries having continuous points.

Comment: Hi @Sarun UK, So could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle by using some sample data?

Comment: please check this fiddle for the sample data for multiple series http://jsfiddle.net/61s2a0r9/

Comment: Thanks @Sarun UK, The problem was caused by missing `x` values in the series.. Please check this corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/brfLdv7o/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thanks for the response. Checked your fiddle. Still, I am not getting the proper tooltip for the hovered series and not even showing the tooltip for overlapping points. Could you please crosscheck your fiddle and verify that something is missing?

Comment: Hi @Sarun UK, It seems to work as expected. Points must have the same x and y values: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q1j23emt/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Added the issue that I am facing in http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/brfLdv7o/. please find an attached image with the question.

Comment: Hi @Sarun UK, Sorry for misunderstanding. The order of the labels was wrong. Please check the corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qc2Ldry8/

Comment: Hi, tooltip is showing properly in this fiddle. But the actual scenario is not covered yet. Not showing multiple tooltip on overlapping points.

Comment: Hi @Sarun UK, Sorry for the inconvenience. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/edqnk8c9/ it should work correctly.

Comment: Hi can you use my sample data for the above fiddle ?

Comment: It looks like you don't have any overlapping points. Please check a simple test in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ry683zso/

Comment: Might be there is no overlapping points. Even though there are overlapping points, tooltip should show only for those series. Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b5u37ewx/

Comment: This should be the solution to all cases: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5gpf71m2/