# how to add onclick event handler inside highcharts tooltip

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts ( Line ) in my php application. I want to use onclick event handler inside the tooltip to open the modal dialog. But i don't find any solution for that, even in highcharts there is no click event available for tooltip item. I also used formatter option inside tooltip but it doesn't worked. Please help me in this issue

I am trying this

```
tooltip: {
    useHtml: true,
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
            s += '<br/><span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>\n\ <span onclick="my_function();">Click Me</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
        });
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
}
```

but my_function is not calling when i click on "Click Me"

Comment: I am trying this

tooltip: {
            useHtml: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {     
                    s += '<br/><span style="color:'+ point.series.color +'">\u25CF</span>\n\
                                <span onclick="my_function();">Click Me</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
                });
                return s;
            },
            shared: true
        },

but my_function is not calling when i click on "Click Me"

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer on my query from highcharts

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
            s += '<br/><span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>\n\ <span onclick="my_function();">Click Me</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
        });
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
}
```

I am doing a spelling mistake by using useHtml but it is actually useHTML. So now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
I added `tooltipClick` class to the span

```
{
    useHtml: true,
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
            s += '<br/><span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>\n\ <span class="tooltipClick">Click Me</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
        });
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
}
```

And delegated an event handler

```
$(document).on('click','.tooltipClick',function(){
      console.log($(this).parent()); //get the tooltip
      alert('a toolip was clicked')
});
```

Comment: No its not working. The problem is that it converted the span to tspan in svg when higcharts was rendered and thats why click event is not working. So there must be a click event for tooltip text like there is a click event for series legend.

Comment: I see, did you see this post? sounds like what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476400/highcharts-keep-tooltip-showing-on-click

Comment: I saw this example already. In this example we have to click on the point and it will make the tooltip fix for that point until other point is clicked. But i want click event for the tooltip text.

Comment: no, I don't think OP is asking for that. I feel he want click event inside tooltip not on points. however when you are on a point ,tooltip will be shown but if you go inside tooltip section tooltip hides

Comment: @Huzefa yes I understand you scenario, but are you sure you can move on tooltip?  means its dis-appeares when you leave series point and try to focus on tooltip area

Comment: Yes i want click event on tooltip text and there is a option to disable the tooltip animation so that it will not hide immediately.

Comment: I see your fiddle example it only works when only anchor tag is passed as html but not working in my scenario because i have to show other info also in tooltip. Look into my code.

Comment: @NishithChaturved i  can see the problem, its when you mouse over the anchor, you no longer have the mouse over the tooltip. I experimented with absolute position of the anchor but the styling of the tool tip was affected http://jsfiddle.net/wbe631rL/

Comment: Put this code 

formatter: function() {
                var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';
                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s += '<br/><span style="color:'+ point.series.color +'">\u25CF</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="my_function();">click me</a> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
                });

                return s;
            },

and try to call my_function it didn't work

Comment: @andrew Replace your fiddle formatter function with mine and make separate my_function() outside the highcharts.