# Best way for debugging Hover state with CSS and JS changes

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, highcharts, hover

I would like to know what is the best/essayist way to debug an HTML element in an Hover state when using a JS library (in my example: Highcharts).
This library is using CSS but also real-time manipulation of the DOM with JS.

For example, in the attached JS fiddle there is an Highcharts Scatter map and I would like to know what are ALL to properties that the tool-tip (that appears when you hover one of the dots) has. 
I saw in similar questions here that in firebug I can simulate the CSS rules of an Hover state for an element, but I did not see any answer about how to debug when CSS and JS are been used together.

Is there any option of "stacking" the page in the hover state, so I could examine the entire state?

[example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h1t2gtk/)

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Sugar and fat intake per country'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.euromonitor.com/">Euromonitor</a> and <a href="https://data.oecd.org/">OECD</a>'
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Daily fat intake'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} gr'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                color: 'black',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 2,
                value: 65,
                label: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    y: 15,
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic'
                    },
                    text: 'Safe fat intake 65g/day'
                },
                zIndex: 3
            }]
        },

        yAxis: {
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Daily sugar intake'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} gr'
            },
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            plotLines: [{
                color: 'black',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 2,
                value: 50,
                label: {
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic'
                    },
                    text: 'Safe sugar intake 50g/day',
                    x: -10
                },
                zIndex: 3
            }]
        },

        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            headerFormat: '<table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            followPointer: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                { x: 95, y: 95, z: 13.8, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium' },
                { x: 86.5, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' },
                { x: 80.8, y: 91.5, z: 15.8, name: 'FI', country: 'Finland' },
                { x: 80.4, y: 102.5, z: 12, name: 'NL', country: 'Netherlands' },
                { x: 80.3, y: 86.1, z: 11.8, name: 'SE', country: 'Sweden' },
                { x: 78.4, y: 70.1, z: 16.6, name: 'ES', country: 'Spain' },
                { x: 74.2, y: 68.5, z: 14.5, name: 'FR', country: 'France' },
                { x: 73.5, y: 83.1, z: 10, name: 'NO', country: 'Norway' },
                { x: 71, y: 93.2, z: 24.7, name: 'UK', country: 'United Kingdom' },
                { x: 69.2, y: 57.6, z: 10.4, name: 'IT', country: 'Italy' },
                { x: 68.6, y: 20, z: 16, name: 'RU', country: 'Russia' },
                { x: 65.5, y: 126.4, z: 35.3, name: 'US', country: 'United States' },
                { x: 65.4, y: 50.8, z: 28.5, name: 'HU', country: 'Hungary' },
                { x: 63.4, y: 51.8, z: 15.4, name: 'PT', country: 'Portugal' },
                { x: 64, y: 82.9, z: 31.3, name: 'NZ', country: 'New Zealand' }
            ]
        }]

    });
});
```

```css
.highcharts-tooltip h3 {
    margin: 0.3em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Add this to my answer, run your JS within the console to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is open your site in Chrome, hit F12 which is the Web developer toolbar, then hover over the element you want to test.

[image]

Then select from the top right the plus sign next to the Thumbtack , select the thumbtack
[image]

Once that is done you can select what state you want

[image]

At that point you would write a css :hover to see the state occur. (copy and save frequently though).

Comment: I know this option, but it doesn't look like there is any change in the HTML page of in the CSS rules when I check the checkbox next to the ":hover" text.

Comment: What I would use this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476400/highcharts-keep-tooltip-showing-on-click to keep your node open so you can do your css edits, you havent exactly specified what CSS changes you are trying to make either.