# customized highchart popup

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have highchart to show some chart, but I need to customized the popup of highchart and I need to add some hyperlink to direct to another file. How can I customized the pop up?

```
$('#graph_unit_dpk').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Trend DPK 2015',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Divisi Data Management',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Rupiah'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'Jt'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [
        ?php if(!empty($emp_unitperf)){?
        ?php foreach($emp_unitperf as $theitem):?
        {
        name: '?php echo $theitem->PRODUCT;?',
        data: [
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "JAN"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->JAN;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->JAN;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "FEB"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->FEB;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->FEB;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "MAR"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->MAR;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->MAR;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "APR"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->APR;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url( ?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->APR;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "MAY"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->MAY;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->MAY;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "JUN"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->JUN;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->JUN;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "JUL"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->JUL;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->JUL;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "AUG"){? 
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->AUG;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->AUG;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "SEP"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->SEP;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->SEP;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "OCT"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->OCT;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->OCT;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "NOV"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->NOV;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->NOV;?,
        ?php }?
        ?php if($emp_profile[0]->BULAN == "DEC"){?
        {
            y: ?php echo $theitem->DEC;?,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(?php echo base_url().IMG_ASSET;? sun.png)'
            }
        },
        ?php }else{?
            ?php echo $theitem->DEC;?,
        ?php }?
        ]
        },
        ?php endforeach;?
        ?php } ?                     
        ]
});
```

And the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts - Keep tooltip showing on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476400/highcharts-keep-tooltip-showing-on-click)

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476400/highcharts-keep-tooltip-showing-on-click

Comment: This is idea on the [UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/1126429-allow-clickable-tooltips). Feel free to vote for it! Most popular ideas are implemented as plugins or directly merged into the core.